# Logic app how to check sftp has file after, 5 min if file is not present

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a scenario where a Logic App will be scheduled to run at 11 am everyday and will move file from one SFTP to another SFTP, which I have done.

I want to add a condition if the first time the file is not present on SFTP then it should check again after 5 min for 3 retry attempts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a condition if the first time the file is not present on SFTP then it should check again

In order to check if the file is present or not, you can use `List files in folder` action.

[image]

Then you can check for file's existance by looping through files inside that folder using `DisplayName` Variable.

[image]

> I want to add a condition if the first time the file is not present on SFTP then it should check again after 5 min for 3 retry attempts.

Whereas For the above requirement, when you want to retry you can use until Action of `Control` Connector.

[image]

Then set its count to 3 from Change Limits. Below is the flow in my Logic app

[image]

In the next step you can use Delay action and set its limits to 5 minutes.
So that for every 5 minutes the flow is going to check whether the file is present or not in sftp for 3 times.

[image]

Below is the whole flow that satisfies your requirement.

[image]